# What is byte size limit in IBM hyperledger chainCode state?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

How much data I can store with `Chaincode` state in IBM hyperledger?

I'm using [IBM Bluemix hosting](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/).

I'm not able to find any link which specifies the size limit.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no size limit in bytes. 
What we have seen with internal testing for one use case, their chaincode wrote so much to the state, that the peers can't transfer it all before the connection times out. So, I guess the answer is no limit, but you are indeed limited by the capacity of your network. I hope this helps.